# BSOD graphic driver nvlddmkm.sys error

Tags: bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

My pc specs :

- Asus p5g MX (motherboard)
- Nvidia geforce 7300gs (graphic card)
- Intel core 2 duo E7500 (CPU)
- windows 7 ultimate x86

I am using my pc like all the day playing music and then I start need for speed mostwanted2005 and suddenly my pc show

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pshv023rqr77l8a/Screenshot_20180508-182646~2.png?dl=0

Can't post photo but above is link for the error picture

And it shutsdown then I restarted it then vertical blue lines as in above photo shows on motherboard splash screen and then it start to "starting window " logo but there will be no vertical line then after that when "welcome" will be shown the screen goes black and after that BSOD shows same error as in above picture and shuts off .
But if I start my window in safe mode it works fine.

I have done nvidia driver clean install but no success as soon as I uninstall drivers then I start window in normal mode it start with big icons and then windows install driver "vga composite..." Then it will ask for restart as I restart again BSOD.
Last dump info

> `================================================== 
>   Dump File : 051118-33711-01.dmp

Crash Time : 5/11/2018 10:41:04 AM

Bug Check String :

Bug Check Code : 0x00000116

Parameter 1 : 0x86934510

Parameter 2 : 0x8ecdca80

Parameter 3 : 0x00000000

Parameter 4 : 0x00000002

Caused By Driver : nvlddmkm.sys

Caused By Address : nvlddmkm.sys+aca80

File Description : NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 185.93

Product Name : NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 185.93

Company : NVIDIA Corporation

File Version : 8.15.11.8593

Processor : 32-bit

Crash Address : ntkrnlpa.exe+def20

Stack Address 1 : dxgkrnl.sys+8d07b

Stack Address 2 : dxgkrnl.sys+81937

Stack Address 3 : dxgmms1.sys+692c

Computer Name :

Full Path : C:\Windows\Minidump\051118-33711-01.dmp

Processors Count : 2

Major Version : 15

Minor Version : 7601

Dump File Size : 209,544

Dump File Time : 5/11/2018 10:42:18 AM

================================================== 
`

sorry for bad English . 
Thanks

Comment: Try an older version of the nVidia driver. What version are you currently trying to install ?

Comment: I am using V308.09  .. older versions I can't find but I will try to find older versions

Comment: Try version 307.83. or 301.42. https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/57493

Comment: @Overmind I downloaded from your link but it shows the graphic driver not  compatible with this version of window. The graphic driver not compatible with graphic hardware

Comment: So I install v307.74 it install but again same problem

Comment: Try to update the chipset drivers prior to installing the video ones.

Comment: Updating chipset driver Not helpful

Comment: Remove any overclocking software if any, reset the BIOS to defaults or update the BIOS. If nothing else works, you may have a problem with insufficient power (dying PSU).

Comment: @Overmind psu :/ , nothing overclocked , already tried resetting bios , but I have not updated bios (I am little concern about it ,is updating bios can not create any problems? ) , Now if my psu is dying then how can I know is there any tests that show my psu is dying ?

Comment: IntelBurnTest is a way of draining some power out of the system for stability tests, but that will be a partial load since the video card is in failsafe mode.